# R DT clips table selection buttons (when text is added to body)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, dt, flexdashboard

**Actual Behavior - Clipping**

I'm using the R DT package with flexdashboard. When I add text to the body of a DT table, the bottom of the dashboard is clipped (to varying extents). See below.

````
---
title: "With text in the body the bottom is clipped"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Notice at the bottom that "Showing X entries" and "Previous/Next" are both clipped

```{r}
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars)
```
````

[image: bottom of dashboard clipped]

**Expected Behavior - No Clipping**

If I remove the text from the body of my table everything behaves as expected. But I want my body text ¯_(ツ)_/¯. What to do?

Is this a bug I should report, or is there another solution I'm unaware of?

````
---
title: "Without text in the body nothing is clipped"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r}
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars)
```
````

[image: not clipped dashboard]

*Version Info:*

```
other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.16             flexdashboard_0.5.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[used this link for intel](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#sizing) just adding `###` in the chart, helped align the table with Flexdashboard margins

````
---
title: "With text in the body the bottom is     clipped"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Notice at the bottom that "Showing X entries" and     "Previous/Next" are both clipped

###
```{r }
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Interesting behavior. Try it with `#` or `##` or varying levels, a different output is returned. It seems as if the header tag is required and must be a specific height.

Comment: some Rmarkdown docs don't render right if there aren't the right Headers from my experience, like you want to try a blank doc, but without a header, it can look weird